# Regex: how to split "a.b" to "a" ".b" in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I saw this [Regex replace `a.b` to `a. b`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50034397/regex-replace-a-b-to-a-b) I don't understand it's for Python not for Javascript or it isn't well explained.

I know how to split "a.b" to ["a" "." "b"] with

```
regex = /(\.)/;
test = "a.b";
results = test.split(regex);
```

I can't see what regex to get

```
["a" ".b"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could split by the positive lookahead of a dot.

```js
var string = "a.b",
result = string.split(/(?=\.)/);

console.log(result);
```